# Creating Product issue in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1

I just installed a magento enterprise vs: `1.14.3.0`. When I want to create a simple product, I'm getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1139 Got error 'this version of PCRE is compiled without UTF support at offset 0' from regexp,
```

query was:

```
SELECT MAX(ABS(CAST(SUBSTRING(`value`, 5, LENGTH(`value`) - 4) AS SIGNED)))
FROM `catalog_product_entity_url_key`
WHERE (value LIKE :url_key) 
AND (entity_id <> :entity_id)
AND ((value REGEXP '^test$') OR (value REGEXP '^test-[0-9]*$'))
```

I'm using lampp as local server. After I installed this package:
`sudo apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev` I'm still getting the error. Did someone get that error message ?  Can you help me fixing it ?

Thx

**[UPDATE]**

I run the following:

```
download latest version 
enter the folder with extracted PCRE and run the following commands
sudo ./configure --prefix=/opt/lampp --enable-utf8 --enable-unicode-properties
sudo make
sudo make install
reboot your pc
```

But I still get the error . This is the result of the pcretest -C command:

```
➜  bin pcretest -C                 
PCRE version 8.38 2015-11-23
Compiled with
  8-bit support
  UTF-8 support
  Unicode properties support
  No just-in-time compiler support
  Newline sequence is LF
  \R matches all Unicode newlines
  Internal link size = 2
  POSIX malloc threshold = 10
  Parentheses nest limit = 250
  Default match limit = 10000000
  Default recursion depth limit = 10000000
  Match recursion uses stack
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of downloading the latest version .I downloaded this version:
ftp://ftp.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/software/programming/pcre/pcre-8.40.tar.gz and I followed these steps:

```
untar downloaded file & go to that directory
sudo ./configure --prefix=/opt/lampp --enable-utf8 --enable-unicode-properties
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

For me it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

This means that your pcre library used in your local server does not support UTF 8. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35801425/xampp-mysql-this-version-of-pcre-is-compiled-without-utf-support-at-offset-0 for the answer.